# The background drawing is different for each browser, which is correct?

Tags: html, css, background

I have created a style that highlights part of a sentence in a paragraph like this:

```css
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.paragraph>span {
  position: relative;
}

.paragraph>span:after {
  background: black;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.2em;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<p class="paragraph">
  Lorem <span>ipsum dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <span>incididunt ut labore</span> et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi <span>ut aliquip ex ea commodo</span>  consequat.
</p>
```

I was testing this with [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4g9j2hv/). I found two problems in Firefox.

1. The highlights are displayed below the text.

[image: Image 1(Firefox version)]

2. The highlights are applied to elements that have no highlights applied. In this figure, the highlight which is applied to "incididunt ut labore" is instead applied elsewhere.

[image: Image 2(Firefox version)]

I tried to see if Google Chrome had the same problem. Then, it became a behavior different from Firefox.

1. The problem of highlights appears below the text has not occurred. And, the problem of highlights being applied to other elements has not occurred. However, the problem that the highlights disappears occurs.

[image: Image 1(Chrome version)],

[image: Image 2(Chrome version)]

### Question

1. By specification, which working of Firefox and Google Chrome  in the image is correct?
2. How can I fix these glitches and always show black highlights?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the use of absolute element on relative inline element when they wrap. It's difficult in this case to define the top/left/right/bottom and each browser implement a different thing.

Simply consider a background coloration and make the color the same as the background and you will have the same highlight effect:

```css
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  padding-top: 1em;
}


.paragraph > span {
  background: black;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<p class="paragraph">Lorem <span>ipsum dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <span>incididunt ut labore</span> et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi <span>ut aliquip ex ea commodo</span> consequat. </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `span`is an inline-element and therefore won't be a valid (relative) anchor for an absolutely positioned element as you are trying it. The position of the absolutely positioned element will instead depend on the next higher relatively positioned parent block (or inline-block) element, which causes the problems you describe.

But why don't you just apply the background (plus another text color and some padding) to the `span` itself? That's much simpler.

```css
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.paragraph>span {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

```html
<p class="paragraph">
  Lorem <span>ipsum dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <span>incididunt ut labore</span> et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi <span>ut aliquip ex ea commodo</span>  consequat.
</p>
```